# Getting the value of blocking curl request in PHP

Tags: php, loops, curl

I have multiple curl requests within a loop. How do I get the response out of it?

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com");

     if(curl_exec($ch)===false){ 
       break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Initiate an array before `for()`, put the result of `curl_exec()` in a variable (say `$result`) and push `$result` in the array if not false.

Comment: I like to use https://github.com/rmccue/Requests for creating requests in PHP, its way easier to use (at least for me) than curl. After request it returns response object with body property, then you can add it to array of results (or you can add whole response object )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s take an example where we need to fetch records from the server based on ids assuming that server will return data for single **id** in a **single** request.

Now, if we use cURL then we need to iterate loop for each **id** and request server therefore if there are **10** ids then on an average response time will be **10X** of a **single** request.

```
$result=array();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
  // URL from which data will be fetched
  $fetchURL = 'https://webkul.com&customerId='.$id;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fetchURL);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $result[] = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

But if use **multiple** cURL requests then response time reduces significantly. To do that you need to first initialize `curl_multi_init()`, push all request to array using `for()` and finally send request to `curl_multi_exec()`

```
// array of curl handles
$multiCurl = array();
// data to be returned
$result = array();
// multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();
foreach ($ids as $i => $id) {
  // URL from which data will be fetched
  $fetchURL = 'https://webkul.com&customerId='.$id;
  $multiCurl[$i] = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_URL,$fetchURL);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $multiCurl[$i]);
}
$index=null;
do {
  curl_multi_exec($mh,$index);
} while($index > 0);
// get content and remove handles
foreach($multiCurl as $k => $ch) {
  $result[$k] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
}
// close
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

**Full Reference:** https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/